# iText 1.4.8 support for Html tag conversion

Tags: java, pdf, itext, richtext, html-to-pdf

I am using Itext version 1.4.8 I cant update the iText version since its been used by the company , I need help in parsing Html content i.e. Rich text into PDF text. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `1.4.8` was released on on Dec 18, 2006. 14 years ago. Tell your company to upgrade. That'll be cheaper than finding someone who is knowledgeable about such an old version _and willing to help you_.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse yes i agree but its a big organization and legal procedure to procure  a licence takes time, need to fix this soon , any work around ?

Comment: Ok understood but what did you try? Where is your problem. You write that you need "to fix this soon" so it can only be some minor issue and not the full requirement from scratch, right? So post your problematic code and somebody here may be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way . Posting it in case someone wants to refer it as a workaround

```
private StyleSheet css  = new StyleSheet();
    
    public static void parse(String htmlInput, Document document)  {
        css.loadTagStyle("body", "size","12px"); //In case u want to override the default font size
        css.loadTagStyle("h1", "size", "15px");
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(HtmlInput); 
        try {
            java.util.List<? extends Element> elements = HTMLWorker.parseToList(reader, css); 
            for (Element element : elements) {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                //Add the cells into a Table
            }
            //Add the Table to the document
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get an ExceptionConverter: java.io.filenotfoundexception: c:\data:image\png;base64 when my htmlInput contains images encoded in base 64, is there a way to handle this case?